# Как восстановить доступ к ресурсу? 2fa gpg4usb

Tags: 2fa, pgp

Создал ключ, поставил на аккаунт, экспортировал его, делал это все в архиве винрар.
Ключ экспортировался. Я проверил работоспособность, работал.

Решил браузер закрыть и по новой перезайти, выдает ошибку, что нет `security key`, посмотрел в интернете, а там он по другому экспортируется, как в итоге получить `security key`, имя лишь `паблик кей`? Прога **`gpg4usb`**

Решил сделать двухфакторную аутентификацию, но не импортировал `security key`, есть только файл с `public key`, как мне достать `security key`, это возможно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Решил сделать двухфакторную аутентификацию, но не импортировал security key, есть только файл с public key, как мне достать security key, это возможно?